# Diagnosing bottleneck or limit in haproxy

Tags: performance, linux-networking, haproxy

I have haproxy in front of a high performance web app. At high volumes ~11k req/sec, the server seems to hit a limit or bottleneck at the haproxy level, while the underlying server can handle more traffic with near zero response latency.

To illustrate, I run curl on a simple hello world test endpoint. Hitting the app directly at port 8080 responds in ~17ms according to `time`. I suspect due to such a crude benchmark setup, the real response time is under 1ms. Going through haproxy port 80 takes over 5 seconds. I assume there is some queue/backlog limit I need to adjust:

```
root@01:/usr/share# time curl http://localhost/hello
hi there!
real    0m5.097s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.012s
root@01:/usr/share# time curl http://localhost:8080/hello
hi there!
real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Running `curl "http://localhost:9000/haproxy_stats;csv" > stats.csv`, I get:

```
# pxname,svname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax,slim,stot,bin,bout,dreq,dresp,ereq,econ,eresp,wretr,wredis,status,weight,act,bck,chkfail,chkdown,lastchg,downtime,qlimit,pid,iid,sid,throttle,lbtot,tracked,type,rate,rate_lim,rate_max,check_status,check_code,check_duration,hrsp_1xx,hrsp_2xx,hrsp_3xx,hrsp_4xx,hrsp_5xx,hrsp_other,hanafail,req_rate,req_rate_max,req_tot,cli_abrt,srv_abrt,comp_in,comp_out,comp_byp,comp_rsp,lastsess,last_chk,last_agt,qtime,ctime,rtime,ttime,
http-in,FRONTEND,,,30000,30000,30000,244107765,170146478342,37776067415,0,0,49255,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,2,0,,,,0,10606,0,25873,,,,0,409162321,0,51319,245288,4921,,12052,26301,409479925,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,
servers,server1,0,0,16076,29017,50000,410260473,170146023052,37766853705,,0,,244621,4917,829803,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,3,1,,409430670,,2,12052,,34968,,,,0,409162321,0,1794,667,0,0,,,,4520,4917,,,,,0,,,0,690,646,1992,
servers,BACKEND,0,0,16076,29964,3000,409430670,170146023052,37766853705,0,0,,244621,4917,829803,0,UP,1,1,0,,0,45940,0,,1,3,0,,409430670,,1,12052,,26301,,,,0,409162321,0,2064,245288,4921,,,,,4520,4917,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,690,646,1992,
stats,FRONTEND,,,2,2,2000,772,86236,1141909,0,0,1,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,4,0,,,,0,1,0,1,,,,0,770,0,1,0,0,,1,2,772,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,
stats,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,200,0,86236,1141909,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,0,0,0,,0,45940,0,,1,4,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,3663,0,2,317,
```

Reformatted in easier to read tabular text (UPDATE: Fixed formatting):

```
# pxname  svname    qcur  qmax  scur   smax   slim   stot       bin           bout         dreq  dresp  ereq   econ    eresp  wretr    wredis  status    weight  act  bck  chkfail  chkdown  lastchg  downtime  qlimit  pid  iid  sid  throttle  lbtot      tracked  type  rate   rate_lim  rate_max  check_status  check_code  check_duration  hrsp_1xx  hrsp_2xx   hrsp_3xx  hrsp_4xx  hrsp_5xx  hrsp_other  hanafail  req_rate  req_rate_max  req_tot    cli_abrt  srv_abrt  comp_in  comp_out  comp_byp  comp_rsp  lastsess  last_chk  last_agt  qtime  ctime  rtime  ttime  
http-in   FRONTEND              29930  30000  30000  260607375  176871559870  39278101192  0     0      50446                                  OPEN                                                                     1    2    0                                  0     11565  0         25873                                               0         425740885  0         52573     286642    5198                  10112     26301         426097360                      0        0         0         0                                                                   
servers   server1   0     0     12061  29020  50000  427063733  176871103092  39268664952        0             285733  5194   1017043  0       no check  1       1    0                                                 1    3    1              426046914           2     10110            34968                                               0         425740885  0         1858      909       0           0                                            5158      5194                                             0                             0      589    664    1931   
servers   BACKEND   0     0     12061  29964  3000   426046914  176871103092  39268664952  0     0             285733  5194   1017043  0       UP        1       1    0             0        47413    0                 1    3    0              426046914           1     10110            26301                                               0         425740885  0         2128      286642    5198                                                     5158      5194      0        0         0         0         0                             0      589    664    1931   
stats     FRONTEND              1      2      2000   798        89114         1181075      0     0      1                                      OPEN                                                                     1    4    0                                  0     1      0         1                                                   0         796        0         1         0         0                     1         2             798                            0        0         0         0                                                                   
stats     BACKEND   0     0     0      0      200    0          89114         1181075      0     0             0       0      0        0       UP        0       0    0             0        47413    0                 1    4    0              0                   1     0                0                                                   0         0          0         0         0         0                                                        0         0         0        0         0         0         0                             3481   0      2      334
```

The one value that looks suspicious is a `slim` of 3000 for servers/BACKEND. How can I adjust that in the configuration? The main servers/server1 shows an `slim` of `50000` which is comfortably above `scur` and `smax` values.

My haproxy.cfg file:

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 300000
    # See running maxconn with:
    # echo "show info" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin
    stats timeout 2m

defaults
    # This doesn't help.
    # maxconn 25000
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    maxconn 30000
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    # This doesn't help.
    # maxconn 25000
    server server1 127.0.0.1:8080 maxconn 50000
    stats enable

listen stats
    bind :9000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy_stats
```

Comment: The column alignment in your table is off.  Your frontends have qcurr and qmax of null (no values between the commas).  Front ends don't have queues.  Any two adjacent commas, you should show in your table as `-`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on fixing that. Linux `column` utility is skipping empty columns.